# Tick marks in axis, scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, scatter

I am making a scatter plot and I am trying to make tick marks every 50 mg from 0 to 350 in the x-axis and tick marks every 25 mg from 0 to 350 for the y-axis.

Here it is my code:

```
cereal <- read.csv("cereal.txt")
attach(cereal)

library(vcd)

plot(sodium, potass, main='Sodium vs Potassium of Cereals', ylab="Potassium", xlab="Sodium")
axis(1,tck=2, at=seq(0,350by=50))
axis(2,tck=2, at=seq(0,350by=25))
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
> axis(1,tck=2, at=seq(0,350by=50))
Error: unexpected symbol in "axis(1,tck=2, at=seq(0,350by"
> axis(2,tck=2, at=seq(0,350by=25))
Error: unexpected symbol in "axis(2,tck=2, at=seq(0,350by"
```

Comment: Do you have data that we can use to test your code?

Comment: you need a , between 350 and by in your seq